# How to find Correct path to save data in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save

I've a game. I should save the game whenever end user exit.
how to know where to save? because If I save the game to the under `C://Users/..` path what happens if user uses **Android** or **IOS**? what is the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Application.persistentDataPath` [method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html).

> This value is a directory path where you can store data that you want
> to be kept between runs. When you publish on iOS and Android,
> persistentDataPath points to a public directory on the device. Files
> in this location are not erased by app updates. The files can still be
> erased by users directly.
>
> When you build the Unity application, a GUID is generated that is
> based on the Bundle Identifier. This GUID is part of
> persistentDataPath. If you keep the same Bundle Identifier in future
> versions, the application keeps accessing the same location on every
> update.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Info : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(Application.persistentDataPath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use application data folder which changes depending on platform.

```
//Attach this script to a GameObject
//This script outputs the Application’s path to the Console
//Run this on the target device to find the application data path for the platform
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    string m_Path;

    void Start()
    {
        //Get the path of the Game data folder
        m_Path = Application.dataPath;

        //Output the Game data path to the console
        Debug.Log("dataPath : " + m_Path);
    }
}
```

Read more about it [here at source](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html)

Comment: On Android it points directly to the APK. This path is Read Only, you wont be able to write to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
There is structure or class and on it base will be better to creating objects and writing its in file.

[System.Serialisable]
public class AAA{
    public string Name = "";
    public int iNum = 0;
    public double dNum = 0.0;
    public float fNum = 0f;
    int[] array;
    // Here may be any types of datas and arrays and lists too.
}


AAA aaa = new AAA(); // Creating object which will be serialis of datas.
// Initialisation our object:
aaa.Name = "sdfsf";
aaa.iNum = 100; 

string path = "Record.txt"
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
    path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, path);
#else
    path = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, path);
#endif

// Writing datas in file - format JSON:
string toJson = JsonUtility.ToJson(aaa, true);
File.WriteAllText(path, toJson);

// reading datas from file with JSON architecture and serialis.. it in object:
string fromjson = File.ReadAllText(path);
AAA result = JsonUtility.FromJson<AAA>(fromjson);
```